# How to route pipes through an already tiled wall?

Tags: tiling

I would like to add a heated towel rail to my central heating system. There is a radiator on the other side of the stud wall I'd like to put the towel rail on so would like to feed some piping through the wall then install the towel rail on the other side.
The wall is tiled. Is the easiest option going to be to remove the tiles or is there a clever way to drill a pipe hole in situ.

Thanks

Comment: what about opening the wall on the radiator side and doing your plumbing from that side, then patch it up?

Comment: That's what I'm hoping to do but I'm not sure how feasible making a hole large enough for pipes is. Everything I've seen on making holes for pipes and fittings has been before the tile is mounted. I know you can drill into tile on the wall but i suspect a hole cutter is an order of magnitude harder. Do you have experience of trying this? Thanks

Comment: Rather than making such modifications to so many things, why not just attach an electrically heated towel rail.  You mount it near an outlet and the only thing needed are a few mounting holes.

Comment: No outlets in the bathroom currently unfortunately. I'd need to do about the same work plus add an rcd to the fusebox. I dont think the region is allowed in the uk either, its over a bath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They make tile cutting hole saws. they can be expensive but a good hole saw in say 1/2 inch pipe diameter will do the job, the trick will be keeping your drill straight against the tile and keeping the tile surface wet - PATIENCE is your friend here.

A couple links but not an endorsement .

[Wet Or Dry Hole Saws](http://www.homedepot.com/b/Tools-Power-Tool-Accessories-Drill-Bits-Hole-Saws-Arbors-Hole-Saws/Tile-(wet-or-dry)/N-5yc1vZc268Z1z0vuj3)

[image: Wet or Dry Hole Saw]

[Diamond Hole Saws](http://www.contractorsdirect.com/Tile-Tools/Diamond-Hole-Saws-Core-Bits)

[image: Diamond Hole saws]

Comment: Accepted ken's answer. Thanks. The links showed a guide which can be used vertically. I think i need the guide,  a hole saw and a steady arm. Thanks everyone who helped.